# Plotting a heat map in R based off a seperate value instead of density

Tags: r, ggplot2

My question is, is it possible to create a continuous heat map using R (not something like tiles on a grid ie. geom_tile) based off a value at a given x,y coordinate as opposed to the density of the x,y points themselves?

For example, If I have a data frame that looks like:

```
x_coordinate = c(-3.459, -2.280, 1.860, 1.770)
y_coordinate = c(4.169, 2.807, 3.835, 1.619)
value = c(56, 96, 112, 90, 82)
```

I would like to create a heatmap thats colour scaled based on the value for each x,y location. Upon searching I'm aware there are a few similar threads to this one, however answers seem to be directed towards creating a grid of some kind, as aforementioned, I'd like to create something continuous that is more akin to a heatmap.

[Something thats somewhat like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtier.png)

Comment: Can you provide any example image what you are looking for?

Comment: I have added a picture example or something perhaps similar to what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: So what about geom_contour? check this link [2d contours of a 3d surface](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_contour.html)

Comment: Geom contour is fine, but what I'm asking is the process of how to construct a heat map based off a variable value instead of the points density.